# Angular 4 lazy load routing - children not loading

Tags: angular

I have a lazy load component, and I have an issue with routing inside of it.

the routes look like this:

```
    const routes:  Routes {
      {path: '': component: ReportsComponent, children:[
         {path: '', component: DeviceReportComponent},
         {path: 'sites', component: SiteReportComponent},
         {path: 'devices', component: DeviceReportComponent}
      ]}
    }
```

now when I navigate to the component, the first route loads perfectly, but any navigation attempt after that is ignored.

any ideas?

Comment: In the code you are showing you misspelled `children`, was this just a typo when copy pasting?

Comment: typo while typing this, the system is in a private network not connected to the internet

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that having two empty paths routing to two different component would cause problems. [this training](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html) shows that the root empty path always routes to a named route with a component:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'product-list', component: ProductList },
  { path: 'product-details/:id', component: ProductDetails,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'overview', component: Overview },
      { path: 'specs', component: Specs }
    ]
  }
];
```

You could try to stick to that template.

Comment: this is a lazy loaded route, and the children are in the child router

Answer (score 0):

ok

after some digging in the code, found the error:
in the main router, I had reports/:type , where the :type obviously had no place there...

Comment: what are you trying to say. Explain it well so that it could help others.